How to install window shades into corner bead
I'm about to install my window shades and it looks like my windows all have some metal running along all corners. This was like that when we moved in so I can only make an educated guess that this is a corner bead. If I want to mount my window treatments into this do I need some self-drilling metal screws? With metal right there I don't plan on using anchors.


Are you doing an "inside" or "outside" mount? A picture would help you get the best answers...

Inside mount. I added an image in the original post

I would strongly reccomend that you place the screws that hold the brackets at least 1" away from the corner. There you will still hit the corner bead but you will also go into the framing behind the drywall. Ideally if you have room to do so, place the screws at least an 1 3/8" to 1 1/2" back. The corner bead in many cases is only 1 1/4" wide on each side. That way there will be no change of the screw threads pulling on the corner bed the wrong way causing the drywall mud and its paint covering to fall off the wall. I am leaving this as a comment, since it doesn't answer the question.

Thanks! That's all helpful. Thanks to this thread my plan is now to set the screws back as far as possible.

Give yourself a little room from the window, even a 1/4". Some of the clips that hold the blinds, in order to remove them take a little room to push the clip back to release the blinds. I would keep them a 1/2" away to keep some "finger room", as long as that does not get the screws too close to the corner bead.


"...do I need some self-drilling metal screws?"

"Self-drilling" screws are special and have a drill bit on the tip; those might work. You could also drill a pilot hole and use a regular sheet metal screw (sometimes called "self-tapping" screws). I prefer to drill my own pilot hole so I can maximize grip when necessary (smaller pilot hole vs. larger hole created by "self-drilling" screws).

"...With metal right there I don't plan on using anchors."

Much depends on the mounting location and weight of the blinds:

If you are hitting the drywall corner-bead then you are very near a corner. If you are far enough away from the corner there may be wood behind the corner bead/drywall. In that case, the best option is to use a screw that's long enough to grip in the wood. If it happens to be hollow, you should use an anchor of some sort (anchor type would depend on the weight of the blinds).

If you are too near a corner you will be screwing into the edge of a piece of drywall, which is not optimal because the only grip your screw will have will be the very thin drywall corner bead. Also, the metal may bend/deform, the joint compound may flake/break, the screw may pull out, the wall surface may deform.



The last statement is a very true issue. If it is possible to install the style of blinds inside the window opening set the front face of the head piece back from the wall surface by an inch or more.

I was planning on having it sit pretty close to the edge to have it flush, approximately 1/4" from the edge.
I used a magnet and it seems the corner bead extends 1.5" out from the edge. Should I try to drill the hole after the corner bead ends?
